# AVD emulator stuck on logo

Tags: android, emulation, android-virtual-device

I have been using Eclipse and then Android Studio to develop a small app and it all (including the emulator) seemed to go reasonably well, until downloading the latest updates for Android Studio.

Now when I try to run the AVD emulator it gets stuck on the android logo and continually refreshes the screen with a white flash, which looks like it is in synch with the logo refreshing, but doesn't get any further.

I have tried numerous different combinations of device, API, resolution, wiping data, running the emulator from the command line, RAM et. al. for the emulator and different resolutions and refresh rates on my Windows 2008 R2 workstation but nothing works. Can anybody suggest where next to look?

Answer (score 0):

Android studio requires a good integration of hardware as well as OS to run properly running emulator see how munch RAM does it takes run emulator during installation of emulator and use a low quality of emulator first because both android studio and emulator requires different memory space. Coming to the OS and studio works better on UBUNTU, LINUX etc instead on windows and using and if u don't have enough RAM u can use pend-drive as ReadyBoost.